# Persist state in localStorage and retrieving state in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am trying to persist the state of Button option value in localStorage when the user selects it and retrieve the state in componentDidMount method but I am getting a null value. When the user navigates back to the page then state value should be there. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

code::

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import Answers from "../Answers/Answers";

class Section extends Component {
    state = {
        que1: "",
        que2: "",
        que3: ""
    };

    handleClick = event => {
        this.setState(
            {
                que1: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
            }

        ),
            () => {
                localStorage.setItem("que1", que1);
                console.log(this.state.que1);
            }
    };

    handleClick2 = event => {
        this.setState(
            {
                que2: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
            }
        ),
            () => {
                localStorage.setItem("que2", que2);
                console.log(this.state.que2);
            }
    };

    handleClick3 = event => {
        this.setState(
            {
                que3: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
            }
        ),
            () => {
                localStorage.setItem("que3", que3);
                console.log(this.state.que3);
            }
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            que1: localStorage.getItem("que1"),
            que2: localStorage.getItem("que2"),
            que3: localStorage.getItem("que3")
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state);

        let styles = {
            width: '50%',
            margin: '0 auto',
            marginBottom: '15px'
        }
        const { history } = this.props;
        const { que1, que2, que3 } = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                <p>1. I was stressed with my nerves on edge.</p>
                <Button.Group widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick} style={styles}>
                    <Answers selected={this.state.que1} style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
                </Button.Group>
                {` `}
                <p>2. I lost hope and wanted to give up when something went wrong.</p>
                <Button.Group widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick2} style={styles}>
                    <Answers selected={this.state.que2} style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
                </Button.Group>
                {` `}
                <p>3. I feel very satisfied with the way I look and act</p>
                <Button.Group widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick3} style={styles}>
                    <Answers selected={this.state.que3} style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
                </Button.Group>
                <p />
                {` `}
                <Button
                    disabled={!que1 || !que2 || !que3}
                    onClick={() => history.push("/section2", [this.state])}
                >
                    NEXT
        </Button>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Section);
```

output ::

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your onclick handlers, you have:

```
    handleClick2 = event => {
        this.setState(
            {
                que2: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
            }
        ),
            () => {
                localStorage.setItem("que2", que2);
                console.log(this.state.que2);
            }
    };
```

In the setState callback, you need to change it to(you logged the correct value, but didn't store it properly):

```
localStorage.setItem("que2", this.state.que2);
```

Comment: When user clicks on next button and comes back to this page then state should be persisted

Comment: It will "persist(kind of)". What is your console.log showing? Are you sure you're populating the value correctly?

For a very brief period of time when you navigate back you will see an empty value in state.que(until the setState is complete).

For example, if you add a componentDidUpdate function, and log the state, you will see the initial empty state, and then the state that is assigned from localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supposed to be the React way of doing it. You should implement a redux workflow here which will help you persist data when navigating between pages. Refer https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react. And when you click on the back button, you can retrieve the values back from the redux store.

Now, in your case change it to

```
handleClick(e) => {
    const value = event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-key').value;
    this.setState({que1 : value});
    localStorage.setItem('que1', value);
};
```

And in the constructor

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {
        que1 : localStorage.getItem('que1') ? localStorage.getItem('que1') : ''
    };
};
```

But this above solution is not at all recommended. Go ahead with the redux approach.